# На что влияет номер версии платформы android NDK при компиляции?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Извините за сумбурный заголовок. Допустим, я создаю NDK проект и в Application.mk прописываю `APP_PLATFORM := android-21`, другими словами, все библиотеки, заголовки будут браться из этой папки при компиляции `"ndk\platforms\android-21\....."`.

Значит ли это, что я скомпиленую библиотеку или бинарник смогу использовать только на Лолипоп телефонах, или что это вообще значит (можно ли сравнивать эти условия с Андроид **SDK**  и т.д.?

Answer (score 1):

В новых версиях на платформе и в NDK добавляются новые возможности. Например, в android-18 добавлен OpenGL ES 3.0 и чтобы его использовать, нужно указывать APP_PLATFORM минимум 18. Но обратная совместимость сохраняется, поэтому, если не использовать новые возможности, то бинарники будут работать и на старых версиях. Но тут lint'а нет, поэтому без необходимости версию лучше не увеличивать.